# Template method for dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, prototypejs

When I look in the dojo documentation for template all I get is for dijit and examples only show you been able to use them in a widgit. I'm looking for the equivalent of the below methods in js prototype

```
var tmpl = new Template(url)
tmpl.evaluate(templateObj)
```

Does dojo have a template method that you can use in a dojo.declare( class ){} like you can do in js prototype. If not how could I go about similar functionality

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in `dojo.string.substitute` (you'll need to `dojo.require("dojo.string")`).

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/string/substitute

[Edit] Also, if you're interested in acquiring a template for use in substitution from a URL on the same server, you may also want to look into `dojo.cache` (which is also what is often used to fetch widget templates):

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/cache.html

To clarify missingno's response, I don't think `dojo.parser` is what you're interested in right now; its job is to scan the DOM and transform DOM nodes into widgets and other Dojo components.  `dijit._Templated` only uses `dojo.parser` when child widgets are involved (i.e. `widgetsInTemplate` is `true`); on the other hand, it uses `dojo.string.substitute` in all cases, to initially parse `${...}` strings (e.g. `${id}`) in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Prototype, but this sounds like [dojo.parser](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/parser.html) stuff. It is what is used by dijit._Templated behind the scenes (you can chack that in the source code if you want...)

Just note that you probably wouldn't need to cal this yourself - there is `parseOnLoad=true` for automatically parsing your initial HTML.